# pdfimages looses rotation done in PDF

Tags: python, shell, pdf, image-processing, rotation

pdfimages looses the rotation information:

> NB: pdfimages extracts the raw image data from the  PDF  file,  without
>          performing  any  additional  transforms.  Any rotation, clipping, color
>          inversion, etc. done by the PDF content stream is ignored.

From: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html

Up to now my application received only PDF files without rotation. Since some days there are PDFs which can images which get rotated in PDF. Running `exiftran -ai` does not help. The rotation seems to be done in PDF :-(

Any idea how to extract the images and honour the rotation info of the PDF?

## Environment

I am looking for a solution in Python or Shell.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing tool or programming solution? In the latter case, which programming environment, which PDF library?

Comment: @mkl I updated the question: shell or python.

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this question.. I have a scanner which will scan images and may (or not) rotate the image within the PDF. I have been looking to extract the rotation and clipping info of the embedded images.